# Magento 2: Redirect to backend customer list from frontend

Tags: magento2, customer, redirect

I'm trying to create a menu to redirect to the client list in the backend.

The menu is:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Core\CoreCrm\Block\TopLink" name="change.customer">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change Customer</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="helper" helper="Gsp\CoreCrm\Helper\Data::getUrlBackendCustomers">
                        <param name="name">value</param>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="change.customer" destination="header.links" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have the next class:

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    const BACKEND_URL_CUSTOMER = 'customer/index/index';

    protected $_helperBackend;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Url $helperBackend
    )
    {
        $this->_helperBackend = $helperBackend;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getUrlBackendCustomers()
    {
        return $this->_helperBackend->getUrl(self::BACKEND_URL_CUSTOMER);
    }

}
```

But this returns a url not correct.

> http://172.16.254.100/admin/customer/index/index/key/1645a44a6fb4d6c4c85e71bcc2e38caa13c6d047f7d5ef19db0eb9a77b2843b4/

When redirecting it takes me to the dashboard and not to the list of clients, this must be because of the key it generates. When it is not validated, it does not access.

How can I get a correct url?